How to Traverse a Python Dictionary While Avoiding KeyErrors?
While parsing a large JSON, it's possible that some keys may only exist in certain circumstances, such as when an error is present. It's not uncommon to get a 200 OK from the server's API, but then the response you got contains errors that should be checked for.
What's the best way to handle this?
I know that using things like get() are one way to handle KeyErrors.
if json.get('errors') is not None:
    do_something

But what if we need to keep going? This feels horrible:
if json.get('errors') is not None:
   if json.get('errors').get('code') is not None:
      if json.get('errors').get('code') != 0:
         this_is_bad_throw_error

Is there a better way? For example, ruby has a dig() method that basically condenses that whole line into x = dig(:errors, :code) and then you just check on x if it's a nil object or not; so 2 lines, instead of 4 (or more if you have to keep going deeper).
I have used try-except before to catch the KeyError, but this isn't an approach I necessarily care for.
I'm not against external libraries, but due to the location of where the code is being run it's extremely beneficial to stick to built-ins.

"try-except ... isn't an approach I necessarily care for" - Why not? If I understand what you're asking, that's actually the most idiomatic approach.

json.get('errors', {}).get('code') is not None

For this example, you might want to rename your dict to avoid confusion with the stdlib json library.

You might want to read about EAFP vs LBYL

Adding to @wjandrea: And the general Python design philosophy (e.g. duck-typing and exceptions as flow control) is very EAFP-centered, in contrast to older languages like C that tend to encourage a LBYL mentality for everything but file I/O (where EAFP is strictly superior to LBYL in basically every language due to the lack of raciness).

You can either:

Provide a defaulted argument argument to get to make it work with a single line (at the slight expense of making some empty dictionaries that may not be needed):
if json.get('errors', {}).get('code', 0) != 0:  # != 0 can become "not in (None, 0)" if the actual value might be None
    this_is_bad_throw_error


Use exception handling to handle KeyErrors from all depths:
try:
    if json['errors']['code'] != 0:  # != 0 can become "not in (None, 0)" if the actual value might be None
        this_is_bad_throw_error
except KeyError:
    # Missing errors or code means no error occurred, continue uninterrupted
    pass




The latter is much cleaner, even if it does require extra indented blocks, and the performance cost is less than you might expect (Python exception handling is not multiple orders of magnitude more expensive than conditional control flow like it often is in languages like C++; there's a cost, especially when the expected case is an exception, but the much simpler code is usually worth it, and in this case, avoiding constructing the empty dict, and avoiding the more expensive general method call dispatch paths in favor of the interpreter special lookup syntax with fast paths, balances things out).

If you're feeling ambitious, it's not hard to write a dig function to emulate the Ruby method:
def dig(container, *keys_or_indices):
    result = container
    try:
        for ki in keys_or_indices:
            result = result[ki]
    except LookupError:  # Common parent of KeyError and IndexError, so like dig,
                         # it works with mappings and sequences
        return None
    return result

and test:
if dig(json, 'errors', 'code') not in (None, 0):
    this_is_bad_throw_error

but I'd be leery of trying to write Ruby in Python, as you're replacing idioms Python developers will recognize with Rubyisms that are liable to confuse maintainers, increasing their workload for minimal benefit, if any.

Implement your own dig() function like Ruby's:
def dictdig(d: dict, *keys):
    for k in keys:
        d = d.get(k)
        if not isinstance(d, dict):
            break
    return d

j1 = {'errors': {'code': 404}}
j2 = {'errors': {}}

print(dictdig(j1, 'errors', 'code'))
print(dictdig(j2, 'errors', 'code'))


Hah, was writing the same thing. A note: dig in Ruby handles both hashes (Ruby's version of dict) and arrays (Ruby's version of list), so this implementation is only handling half of that implementation (admittedly all the OP seems to be using, but if you're going to actually name it dig, I'd go for feature-compatibility to avoid confusing both Python and Ruby programmers).

It wouldn't be hard to implement something more general, but I just renamed it to dictdig() for simplicity.

That's perfectly reasonable, especially since the OP seems to want to avoid exceptions-as-flow-control (and without them, a dig that handles both mappings and sequences starts getting a lot uglier).

Have you considered using JSON pointers? (RFC 6901). They're like an XPath for JSON. There's a library in pip.
So to grab the first error code in an array of error objects you might do something like this:
from jsonpointer import resolve_pointer
error_code = resolve_pointer(json_behemoth, '/long/path/to/errors/0/code', None)

This library also allows you to change the JSON structure.
